# Selenium Selecting multiple items

Tags: selenium

Hi I am not use to using the press keys keyword but I am having challenges with selecting multiple items.

I am trying to select one item and then hold down the control key to select the other item. It seems to select one item but never both.

Here is what I have and I am wondering if my syntax is wrong:

```
Press Keys        //label[text()='Highest']    SHIFT+CTRL   
sleep   2
Press Keys          //label[text()='Normal']      SHIFT+CTRL
```

I was expecting this to select the first item and hold down the control key and select the second item to where it selected both items.

Comment: Post the maximum code you've tried and also the URL, and explain the problem clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by changing the press keys on both lines to Click Element. I thought Press Keys would work but it didn't